# Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0}config-property'

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.projectodd.vdx.core.XMLStreamValidationException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1182,67]
Message: ParseError at [row,col]:[1182,67]
Message: WFLYCTL0198: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0}config-property' encountered
at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterSubsystemParser.readElement(ResourceAdapterSubsystemParser.java:490)
at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterSubsystemParser.readElement(ResourceAdapterSubsystemParser.java:131)
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml_16.java:673)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_16.java:243)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_16.readElement(StandaloneXml_16.java:140)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:144)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52)
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
... 3 more

Getting Above error while deploying JBOSS servers

## standaloneFull.xml --------

```
`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
<resource-adapters>
        <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar" statistics-enabled="true">
            <archive>wmq.jmsra.rar</archive>
            <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
            <connection-definitions>
                <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/jms/ExampleMDPQConFactory" pool-name="ExampleMDPQConFactory">
    <config-property name="channel">WS_FT_HG.CH</config-property>
        <config-property name="hostName">localhost</config-property>
            <config-property name="transportType">CLIENT</config-property>
            <config-property name="queueManager">WS_FT_HG.QM</config-property>
            <config-property name="port">1414</config-property>
                <xa-pool>
                    <max-pool-size>1500</max-pool-size>
                </xa-pool>
                    <timeout>
                        <xa-resource-timeout>300</xa-resource-timeout>
                    </timeout>
                </connection-definition>`
```

Trying to start the servers , but servers not getting started due to above exceptions

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you attempting to start?